# NPM Installing non root dependencies under node_modules?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm

The project [`@superflycss/component-navbox`](https://github.com/superflycss/component-navbox/blob/master/package.json) has the following dependencies:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@superflycss/component-body": "^1.0.1",
        "@superflycss/component-display": "^1.0.2",
        "@superflycss/component-header": "^2.1.0",
        "@superflycss/component-test": "^3.6.14",
        "@superflycss/foundation": "^2.0.3",
        "@superflycss/superflycss": "^1.0.0",
        "@superflycss/utilities-colors": "^3.0.8",
        "@superflycss/utilities-effects": "^2.1.0",
        "@superflycss/utilities-fonts": "^3.3.7",
        "@superflycss/utilities-format": "^1.1.1",
        "@superflycss/utilities-layout": "^4.0.4",
        "lite-server": "^2.4.0",
        "npm-check-updates": "^2.15.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@superflycss/variables-dimension": "^2.0.0",
        "@superflycss/variables-layout": "^2.0.0"
    }
```

So when doing:

```
git clone git@github.com:superflycss/component-navbox.git

cd component-navbox
npm i
```

I would expect only the root dependencies to show up in the `node_modules` folder.

However another dependency `variables-colors` also shows up in `node_modules`.

IIUC this should not happen or am I missing something?

One of the problems with this is that the `variables-colors` version being installed is outdated, however since `utilities-colors` also depends on this, it uses the older version rather then the newer, and that leads to linting errors, etc.

Comment: Node bug report: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25555

Comment: https://npm.community/t/npm-is-installing-non-declared-root-dependencies/4761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mismatch between `package-lock.json` and `package.json`.  I removed the lock file and also `node_modules` and did `npm i` and it refreshed with all the dependencies being correct.